# Cournot Duopoly firms guaranteed to produce the same amount

Tags: oligopoly

If a market is given to be a Cuornot duopoly and Q = q1 + q2. What assumptions can you make about q1 and q2 being equal? Is it possible for q1 > q2 and thus for company 1 to have greater market share in an equilibrium?

Edit: I assume they have the same cost and indistinguishable products. I guess my question could be more simply boiled down to: Are they guaranteed to have inverted reaction functions?

Comment: Hint: Try solving the problem with $MC_1<MC_2$, namely, firm 1 is more efficient / has a lower marginal cost than firm 2.

Comment: @HerrK. yes, oops meant to assume, that. I think I need to focus on the reaction function I am just not sure how to prove they have the same reaction function

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by an *inverted* reaction function?

Comment: @Citrus I mean would one firms reaction function necessarily be the inverse of the other firms reaction function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if firms have identical technologies and identical reaction functions, the Cournot equilibrium can be asymmetric, as shown there:

Amir, Rabah & Garcia, Filomena & Knauff, Malgorzata, 2010. "Symmetry-breaking in two-player games via strategic substitutes and diagonal nonconcavity: A synthesis," *Journal of Economic Theory*, 145, 1968-1986.

Further restrictions on the reaction functions are necessary to guarantee a symmetric equilibrium. A sufficient condition is that they are identical and linear in $y_i$.